# How to ignore jQuery accordion click event for the nested <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have got this code

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1 <a href="www.google.com">Google</a> </h3>
  <div>
      Text...
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
   Text...
  </div>  
</div>
```

And I cannot get working `<a>` tag within a `<h3>` coz the **jQuery accordion** expan/collapse event happans.

How to **avoid** that event so `<a>` is working ***independently*** from accordion event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution that is working fine for me.

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1 <a href="www.google.com" class="openLink" onclick="OpenLink(this);">Google</a> </h3>
  <div>
      Text...
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
   Text...
  </div>  
</div>

 function OpenLink(element)
    {
        console.log(element.href);
        window.location = element.href;
        return false;
    }
```

and there is another  solution

```
$('.openLink').bind('blur change click error keydown keypress keyup mousedown mouseenter mouseleave mousemove mouseout mouseover mouseup', function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

can you post the code or a link to the jquery plugin that you are using? It sounds like the jquery code is running the function preventDefault() and the a tag is bubbling up and hitting that event.

you could wrap an event on the anchor like

```
$('#accordian').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.stopPropogation();
    window.location.href = this.href;
});
```

now becareful with this code if you add an element inside the anchor tag. If you click on that element it won't be the anchor starting the event and it would have the href attribute.

Comment: I use jQuery Accordion plugin with a min configuration.

Comment: Give my code a try, it should work, if it doesn't I can take a deeper look.

Comment: Well... Sorry it doesnt. Even this solution http://cmar.me/2011/06/15/links-in-jquery-accordion-headers/ also.

Answer (score 2):

The event propagate, you could stop the event propagation when someone click over the `<a>` tag. I believe this could work.

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function (e) {e.stopPropagation();});
```

Add the class link to the `<a>` if you want 'link' has a selector.

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1 <a class="link" href="www.google.com">Google</a> </h3>
  <div>
    Text...
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    Text...
  </div>  
</div>
```